# How to add columns to a listview in visual basic?

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably an easy question, but I am new to visual basic and I'm following tutorials online, I have this to add columns to a listview, but I'm getting compilation errors. How do I add columns?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    ListView1.Columns.Add("Column1", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Column2", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Column3", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Column4", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)

End Sub
```

And do you know any good manuals for vb? Most of what I've found aren't as clear as tutorials for other languages.

Thanks

Comment: "I'm getting compilation errors" means nothing, if you don't tell us what "compilation errors" you're getting. We can't see your screen from here, or read your mind. The compiler is telling you what the error is (if it wasn't, you wouldn't know you're getting errors), so you have the information. If you want us to help you, please [edit] your question and be more specific. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked.

```
ListView1.View = lvwReport
ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add , , "COLUMN1", 100
ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add , , "COLUMN2", 100
ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add , , "COLUMN3", 100
ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add , , "COLUMN4", 100
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are wanting to call `ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add` instead of `ListView1.Columns.Add`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it only worked after I added ListView1.View = lvwReport